# jQuery update DOM to access injected html tags

Tags: dom, jquery

Ok I'm submitting a form via ajax. The result string is a bunch of html links and images which I append to the body of the DOM.
Is it possible to search with jQuery within this new code?

before ajax request:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

after ajax request:

```
<div id=results"> 
  <img src="somevalidpicture.jpg" class="image"/>
  <img src="somevalidpicture2.jpg" class="image"/>
</div>
```

How can I run my jQuery code to manipulate that code again? For example:

```
$(".image").show(slow);
```

I suspect I cannot access the .image class, because it wasn't there when the page first loaded. And it doesn't show up in the sourcecode (browser). Is there a way to refresh/update the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* access them, as soon as the elements are added to the DOM `$(".image")` will find them.  However `slow` needs to be in quotes for your particular example:

```
$(".image").show("slow");
```

`"show"` is a key that means 600ms, `$(".image").show(600);` would have the same effect.

---

Don't use "View Source" to see what's currently in your page (since it'll show what was there when the page loaded), instead use a DOM inspector like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the [Chrome Developer tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, you're right - that line was just out of my head. I wanted to know where I have to place my $(".image") command? Does it have to be after the $.ajax() part or somewhere particular?

Comment: Or a better question, is the ready event called again, after an ajax request?

Comment: The $(".image").show('slow') needs to be in a callback function. Typically, it would looks something like this:

$.ajax({ ..., success : function(){ $(".image").show("slow") } });

Comment: That works for me with classes or tags which were there before I did the request, but newly added aren't recognized somehow

Comment: I can't even hide them with $('img').hide(); on $.ajax{ success:... } or .ajaxComplete eventhough those events get called

Comment: @jfrakes - make sure you're calling `$(".image")` *after* the elements are added.